# How set line spacing in Oracle APEX's Rich text editor?

Tags: ckeditor, oracle-apex

I am using APEX 22.1.2. I have a text editor that I need to make the space between lines smaller. How to do so?

Comment: This sounds like you're chasing a CSS property like line-height: 80%;

Comment: Looked closer, my answer in https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4502779/change-line-space-in-a-rich-text-editor covers this, looking at margin-block-start and margin-block-end